# I am trying to rescale numeric columns in a dataframe that is slightly different from the MinMaxscaler approach

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called df that contains 6 numeric columns.
What I want to do is rescale each attribute by subtracting the max
value of a given column from the column value  and then divide
that by the difference of the max and min value for the given
column.
I'm also including some multiplication and addition to this
rescaling.
The rescaling is slightly different from the MinMaxScaler class.

```
    numeric_attribs=list(df)
    analyMaxColValues = df.max()
    analMinColValues = df.min()
    df_max= analyMaxColValues.to_frame()
    df_min= analyMinColValues.to_frame()
        
        
        for i, j, k in zip(numeric_attribs , df_max.index, 
    df_min.index):
            df[i]=(.999*((df[i]-df_max[j].values)/df_max[j].values-
            df_min[k].values)))+ .0005
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned:

*"What I want to do is rescale each attribute by subtracting the max value of a given column from the column value and then divide that by the difference of the max and min value for the given column. I'm also including some multiplication and addition to this rescaling."*

Based off of this, correct me if I'm not getting this correctly but, the steps that you're trying to accomplish seem to be:

- subtract max value of a column from all rows in that column
- divide the result of step 1 by the difference of the max and min value in each respective column
- multiply 0.999 and add 0.0005 to the result of step 2 (from your code)

This can be easily accomplished by the following two lines of code:

```
for i in df.columns:
     df[i] = 0.999 * ( df[i].values - df[i].values.max() ) / (df[i].values.max() -df[i].values.min() ) + 0.0005
```

Comment: Thank you Adib. This worked!!! What if I wanted to apply the min and max values from the df dataframe  to a different dataframe df_x ?  How would I do that

Comment: In this case, if we assume that both your data frames have the exact same column names, and taking the different data frame name as `df_x`, you can just change the 2nd line to 
```
df_x[i] = 0.999 * ( df_x[i].values - df[i].values.max() ) / (df[i].values.max() -df[i].values.min() ) + 0.0005
``` 
and it should work as desired.

Comment: Thanks Adib. That did the trick. I did not think it would be that simple. It's more intuitive than I thought. I'm an old SAS programming getting familiar with python.

Comment: Glad I was of help :)